# Do webdevelopers need "confim resend" protection?

Tags: firefox, post, confirmation

I use firefox for my web development and I bet most of you guys too. I've been doing a lot of form development recently and this annoying message

> "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

is just beginning to piss me off.. I mean, come on! I don't need protection on my localhost, thank you! So, my question is: are you aware of any config, hack, plugin to suppress it? If not, how do you live with it?

Comment: Don't blame the "protection". Blame the developer who wrote the offender using POST and not an appropriate GET or whatnot.

Comment: You don't get it..I'm the developer and have to do a lot of "resend post" testing..

Comment: Use forms which perform a redirect after processing a POST to avoid this problem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Guys, I'm aware of doing a redirect after post. It is only possible after form object has been serialized in database. When you form contains errors you have to display a form with data, so you can't do redirect. And in the process of development you may want to see (quite often) how your form looks like with errors..

Comment: @Dziamid, but in those situations, why are you refreshing the page?  Why not just re-click on the submit button?

Comment: True, I did not think of that =) Thank you. Also, I usually prevent forms to be submitted with enter (for clients), so I guess I will enable it for myself and use Enter instead of F5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is neither configuration option nor extension to turn off this annoying confirmation window.

However, the workaround I use is as follows.

Download and install application AutoHotkey from: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Create the following script:

```
^f5::
Send {f5}
sleep 100
Send {enter}
```

Save with .ahk extension.

Double click to run it (a new icon should show up in the system tray).

Now every time you press Ctrl+F5, the script presses F5 and then Enter. Voila, the confirmation window supressed.

Comment: Great! Finally, no more dump clicking. Automation rocks. But, since I'm a unix guy, I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an equivalent of Patrick's answer for Linux users (Ubuntu in my case).
Install autokey (it's in the repos). Add this python script:

```
import time
keyboard.send_keys("<f5>")
time.sleep(0.5)
keyboard.send_keys("<enter>")
```

Hook this script to f5 and you will never see the confirm message again. Tested with latest firefox.